# What is the real distinction between algebra and geometry?

Tags: geometry

I am much more comfortable doing algebra than using general geometric arguments.  For instance, if I'm intersecting a plane with a sphere, I always think in terms of the generic algebraic equations for a sphere and a plane, set them equal, and solve algebraically.  A geometric argument would say "the intersection is a circle", but I always ask: which circle?  Could the circle be found without algebraic representations of the two objects?

I suppose the question really is, if you don't have algebraic representations of geometric objects, what can you do?

Comment: Quite a lot. Most of high school competition geometry problems, as far as I know, are intended to be solved without use of vectors and coordinate systems, but rather working only with distances and angles. Euclid's "Elements" also does not use algebra in its geometry.

Comment: In general, your description of objects becomes more "local" and based on interrelationships, rather than external. You can't say "the circle with this equation" (invoking an all-seeing frame of reference, the coordinate axes), but instead "the circle with this center through that point," always basing your description on some given, internal objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at Robin Hartshorne's book "Introduction to Projective Geometry", which starts from four axioms for an affine plane, and a corresponding four axioms for a projective plane.

There are three more axioms that often get added for projective planes to restrict to "more interesting" ones. If you start with these seven purely geometric axioms (they are things like "for any two distinct points there is a unique line containing them") you can prove a quite remarkable theorem, namely, the existence of coordinates in the affine plane that results from deletion of any line from the projective plane.

In short: at least in the context above, you can do everything algebraic purely geometrically, because the geometric axioms imply the existence of the algebraic structure.

Of course in practice, working with algebra is often easier and quicker, and I'm a big fan of it.

Comment: Interesting, but it still begs a question.  Taking that axiom "for any two distinct points there is a unique line containing them", am I right to say the following: geometrically, there is an object called a line that is unique that connects those two points.  In 2D and 3D, we can just draw the line and see it.  However, in n-dimensions, we cannot just "draw the line", and as a result are forced to use algebraic representations of it in order to know exactly which line it is?

Comment: Actually, in "synthetic projective geometry" and "synthetic affine geometry" the notions of "point" and "line" are left undefined; the axioms only say things about the relations among these undefined notions. As it happens, all the things that the affine-plane axioms say about points and lines happen to be true for (ordinary) points and lines in $2$-dimensional euclidean space, and those for affine 3-spaces happen to be true for euclidean 3-space, and similarly for higher dimensions. They also happen to be true for many other spaces, though, so the generalization is valuable.